# How to display nested model as list of its first field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models with many-to-many relation.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     tests = models.ManyToManyField(to='Test', null=True, related_name='models')


class Test(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to display 'MyModel' as a list of its 'value' field. 
Here are my serializers (pretty simple as well):

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ('value',)


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    models = MyModelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Test
        fields = ('name','models')
```

So far I get a list of objects:

```
"name": "",
"models": [
    {
        "value": "question"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to display 'value' fields as a list of strings not a list of objects?

**Important**, I would like to avoid serialization methods or any methods in models. Is there any built-in way?

**UPDATED**
If anyone is interested in solution I end up overriding 'to_representation method in `MyModelSerializer` and got desired result.
Here is a serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `values_list` method.

```
items = MyModel.objects.all().values_list('values', flat=True)
```

The result of this will be a list of strings representing the value stored in the 'values' field.

Comment: I would like to avoid any methods in serializer and model. Is there any built-in method like ListField for many-to-many?

Comment: [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) is the built in way. It's a method used on a QuerySet, not the model instance. If that does not match your criteria, I do not think there is any other "built in" way of achieving this.